# How to display multiple PDF files in a node

Tags: nodes, files

I want to display multiple pdf files in a single node. I am using [PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf) module to display pdf files with [File Resumable Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup). But I need to display many files in a single node. I wasnt able to find any solution to this.
When I select multiple files to upload, all get uploaded successfully in the uploads directory, but only one gets displayed. When I go to 'Edit' tab on the same newly created node, all the pdf files are present in the designated section
, but only one is displayed on the node (even after saving again).

Answer (score 0):

Check maybe the Field Settings (/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields/...) of your page if the displayed "Number of values" is set to "Unlimited" instead of 1.

Comment: Yes the field setting in "unlimited", but I need it unlimited, It is working fine for a single file. Isn't there any viewer or technique which can display files one after the other ?

Comment: Done. I just reinstalled PDF module, and everything became normal.